# Unable to authenticate using google apps script (javascript) for fantasy premier league API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch, csrf-token

If anyone can help me out with authenticating for the FPL team API I would be very grateful-
Link is here:
https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/my-team/6803860/
Which works for me in the browser (when I am logged in to the site) but will return "Authentication credentials were not provided". for you and also for me when I am trying to access via AppScript (to bring the data into GoogleSheets).

After looking into it using dev tools and postman, I now know that I need to get a csrf token by logging in then save the token to use when I make the request for the league standings.

I've had what i thought was a good stab it at but it doesn't seem to work (doesnt return a csrf cookie or give me a success message)...

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and also what the next steps would be to take that cookie and get data from the endpoint above?
THANKS!

```
function FPLAPIAuth() {
  var formData = {
  'login' : 'EMAIL',
  'password': 'PASSWORD',
  'redirect_uri': 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/login',
  'app': 'plfpl-web',
  };

  var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'payload' : formData,
};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/",options);
  Logger.log(response.getAllHeaders());
}
```

Comment: Dont konw why i've been downvoted- if anyone needs any more info to help solve this i can provide!

Comment: When you run the above code what does your log show for getAllHeaders?

Comment: [19-09-26 20:55:53:332 BST] {Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Server=nginx/1.13.5, Connection=keep-alive, x-served-by=cache-lhr7355-LHR, cache-dca17745-DCA, Last-Modified=Wed, 25 Sep 2019 10:18:03 GMT, Date=Thu, 26 Sep 2019 19:55:53 GMT, x-cache-hits=0, 0, Via=[1.1 google, 1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish], X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN, Accept-Ranges=[bytes, bytes, bytes], ETag=W/"5d8b3edb-9831", Content-Encoding=gzip, x-timer=S1569527753.237742,VS0,VE82, Vary=Accept-Encoding, x-cache=MISS, MISS, Age=[0, 0], Content-Type=text/html}

Comment: The csrf token is embedded in the page that is served when you first try to access it.  You will have to search for the hidden element with attribute `name = "csrfmiddlewaretoken"` and get the token value. The hidden element will look something like this `<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="TokenhereONo3zPt1hOEOr2BWDS6S5pl2BxVXjHFI8O9xo15Z">`

Comment: Thanks. How do I search for a hidden element? Also, from what I have read there should be some of of success message but I haven't found it. This link shows how to authenticate with python for this API https://medium.com/@bram.vanherle1/fantasy-premier-league-api-authentication-guide-2f7aeb2382e4

Comment: I've made a fairly pathetic attempt to unhide that element below but can't get it to work...
`var output = response.getContentText();
output.querySelector("csrfmiddlewaretoken").setAttribute("hidden", "false");
Logger.log(output);`
I get an error saying that you cant use query selector on that output which is fair enough!